# I want to align the text in my list element that contains a time element

Tags: html, css

I have problem because my elements are not well align *vertically downward* the test after the "-" starts haphazardly.

I have tried enclosing the time tag with `div` elements and align them so that all the `time` elements take-up equal space but this does not work it instead separates the `<li>` into various blocks.

```css
#time-line{
    max-width: 700px;
    margin:0 auto 0 auto;
    font-family:Georgia, 'Times New Roman', Times, serif;
}
ul{
    line-height: 2em;
}
.dates{
    font-weight:bold;
}
```

```html
 <section id="time-line">
            <h2>Follow His Timeline.</h2>
<!--List Element I want to align-->
        
    <ul><!--when the code displays the hyphens are not all vertically on a straight line I have tried adding <div> to them and give them a specific with but in does not display them in line it breaks the contain-->
            <li><time datetime="1901-09-21" class="dates">Sep 21, 1901 - </time></span> Knrumah is born in Ghana.</li>
            <li><time datetime="1935-08-07" class="dates">Aug 07, 1935 - </time>Moved to America and goes to Lincoln University.</li>
            <li><time datetime="1939-05-22" class="dates">May 22, 1939 - </time>Graduation from University</li>
            <li><time datetime="1945-09-09" class="dates">Sep 09, 1945 - </time>Moves to London and he helped to organize the Fifth Pan-African Congress.</li>
            <li><time datetime="1947-05-11" class="dates">May 11, 1947 - </time>Wrote his first book, <cite id="book-title">"Towards Colonial Freedom"</cite></li>
```

Comment: consider a monospace font for the date

Comment: `the test after the "-"` *text*?

Comment: I tried using mono-space but it makes the design less good I think it was best to just add width to the .dates alone

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add width to .dates itself and change its `display` property because `width` won't wrok for inline elements. I moved the character '-' outside `<time>` so it looks nicer. You can also wrap this in `<span>` and give some margin to make space so it looks even more nicer.

```css
#time-line{
    max-width: 700px;
    margin:0 auto 0 auto;
    font-family:Georgia, 'Times New Roman', Times, serif;
}
ul{
    line-height: 2em;
}
.dates{
    font-weight:bold;
    width: 110px;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
 <section id="time-line">
            <h2>Follow His Timeline.</h2>
<!--List Element I want to align-->
        
    <ul><!--when the code displays the hyphens are not all vertically on a straight line I have tried adding <div> to them and give them a specific with but in does not display them in line it breaks the contain-->
            <li><time datetime="1901-09-21" class="dates">Sep 21, 1901</time> -  Knrumah is born in Ghana.</li>
            <li><time datetime="1935-08-07" class="dates">Aug 07, 1935</time> - Moved to America and goes to Lincoln University.</li>
            <li><time datetime="1939-05-22" class="dates">May 22, 1939</time> - Graduation from University</li>
            <li><time datetime="1945-09-09" class="dates">Sep 09, 1945</time> - Moves to London and he helped to organize the Fifth Pan-African Congress.</li>
            <li><time datetime="1947-05-11" class="dates">May 11, 1947</time> - Wrote his first book, <cite id="book-title">"Towards Colonial Freedom"</cite></li>
```